# Maximum of Frechet Distributions

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider $Z_i$ with $i=1,...,n$ a family of independent Frechet random variables with parameters $\varepsilon$ and $B_i$, i.e. the CDF of $Z_i$ is $G(z)=e^{-\left(\frac{z}{B_i}\right)^{-\varepsilon}}$ for $z>0$

I think the distribution of the random variable $Y=\max(X_1,...,X_n)$ is Frechet with parameters $\varepsilon$ and $(B_1^\varepsilon+\cdots+B_n^\varepsilon)^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}$ but I'm unable to find a proof of this result. Does anyone know a reference where I can find more information? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proof, let $F_Y$ be the CDF of $Y$, then by definition
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\leq y)=\Pr(X_1\leq y,\dots,X_n\leq y)=\prod_{i=1}^n \Pr(X_i\leq y)=\prod_{i=1}^n G_i(y)$$
where the step to the product is given by independence. Using the definition of the individual CDF and the properties of exponential function one gets
$$F_Y(y)=\exp\left(-\left(\frac{y}{(B_1^\varepsilon+\cdots+B_{n}^\varepsilon)^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}}\right)^{-\varepsilon}\right)$$
which gives $Y\sim Frechet(\varepsilon, (B_1^\varepsilon+\cdots+B_{n}^\varepsilon)^{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}})$.